# Video downloaded from download manager class is not showing up in the gallery

Tags: java, android, download, android-download-manager

I have created an application where user can download reels from Instagram using its link.
Video is being downloaded perfectly and I can see that video in file manager.
The problem is that this video is not showing in the gallery.

Below is my download method where I have defined my destination file where video will be stored after the download. Is there any process or permission that I am missing ?

public class downLoadMethod {

```
public static String instagramFileName = "/Download/InstaReel";
public static  void download(Uri downloadPath,String destinationPath , Context context , String     filename){

    Toast.makeText(context,"Downloading started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadPath);
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setTitle(filename);
  
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,destinationPath);
    ((DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)).enqueue(request);

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[] { Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() },
            null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)); // out is your output file
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    } else {
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS))));
    }
}
```

}

I was tried to download video from reel using its link through Download manager class. I expected it to be downloaded and show up in the gallery but it is shown only in the file manager not in gallery after the download finished.

Comment: `String destinationPath` Which value did you give it?

Comment: It could help if you just told in which directory the file was saved.

Comment: You should scan the file. Not directories.

Comment: can you plzz explain how to do that ?  destinationPath == "/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4"

Comment: You did not read my first comment?

Comment: I gave you the value of destinationPath in my previous comment

Comment: That is no value. That is code. Code for a file name. Not a file path.